# Does my companion app infringe copyrights?

Tags: android, copyright, board-game

I'm making an android app that is supposed to be just a companion app for a board game. Twilight Imperium 4 is the game, and it has a boatload of techs/actions cards/strategy cards with tons of text on how they work, so the point of the app is to make it easier to look through game effects. It does not intend to be a copy of the game or to replace the gameboard at all.

So, given this context, would it be ok to try and sell it on GooglePlay or would this violate copyright in some way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking. For specific legal advice. This sort of thing is something best asked of a legal professional; it depends on what content you use from the original game and how you use it.

Comment: When you do further research on your own, don't forget that you don't just need to worry about copyrights but also about trademarks. It's a related area of law, but with notable differences.

Comment: A general rule for copyrights is, if you hurt what you are copying, or you earn money because of it, you are most likely doing something that someone can sue you for. Exception would be of course if you had a special contract with the people that made that board game. If you were to release that app for free, it would still most likely violate copyrights, but if it helps make the board game better, there's a chance its makers wouldn't bother.